# fetching value from database and displaying it in a TextView in android

Tags: android

How can fetch values form database and display it in a textview in android?

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#db

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good to see you've given it some thought and tried on your own.

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#db has some good info on using SQLite on Android

It's also used in the Notepad tutorial: http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/notepad/notepad-ex1.html

I personally learned by using part of the guide from the "Hello, Android" book. The source code is available at: http://www.pragprog.com/titles/eband3/source_code - the SQL example is the one called 'Eventsv1'

Answer (score 0):

You need SQLiteOpenHelper class to fetch readable instance of SQLiteDatabase in android. Then using query method you can get Cursor object of you query.

Can you explain more about what you want to do?
Try this,

```
Cursor c =  db.query(TABLE_NAME, columns, null, null, null, null, null);
```

Then write

```
if(c!=null) {
                c.moveToFirst();


                while(!c.isAfterLast()) {

                    String col1Value = c.getString(1);//here you get col1 value
                    String col2Value = c.getString(2);//here you get col2 value

                    c.moveToNext();

                }
                c.deactivate();
                c.close();
            }
```

Comment: i want to fetch data from the database by querying and display the feilds in different textviews.